# Toshiba Tecra A11 laptop stays "on" after shutdown

Tags: laptop, motherboard, shutdown

Bit of a strange one. I hope I posted on the correct site.

When I shut down the laptop, the screen goes off and the fans shut down, but the power light stays on. On the front of the laptop, there are three main lights that are associated with the power.

There is the Plugged in light, the power light and the battery light.

When the laptop is running when plugged in, all three of those lights are on. When the laptop is running **not** plugged in, the battery and power light are on.

**The problem**

Now, when I shut the machine down - note: not sleep / hibernate (as evidenced by using `shutdown -f`) - everything goes off as normal, but the power light stays on.

With the power light still on, it is still generating heat at this time. I put my hand next to the exhaust port on the left and can feel the heat coming out, which is different to when it is powered off. When you shut the laptop, a minute later or so the fans kick in.

This is all *very* odd behaviour for a computer that isn't supposed to be on.

**What I have tried**

Unfortunately, I have limited knowledge on laptop hardware.

I have had a look in the BIOS for any power options that may have changed some how, but surprisingly [sarcasm overload!], I didn't see anything that looked like it controlled duration of time the machine stays powered.

This problem occurs if it is plugged in or running only from the battery. The laptop is about 13-14 months old.

*EDIT:*

I removed the battery and plugged it in booted it up and then ran the shutdown procedure. It shuts down fine (all lights go off, no fans running).

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? Of course taking it to a computer repair place / sending it back is my last resort, because the machine is in use every day. And that also costs money.

TIA :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by oddly enough, removing the battery then replacing it. I don't know why this would cause it to stay powered on.

Answer (score 1):

Check the BIOS for options like "wake on lan". For these to work the motherboard needs to have power.

Comment: +1 A good suggestion, but it was not the solution. Good to know though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as described.  The solution I found was in regards of the USB charging feature that remains on after shuting down the laptop. This is to allow phone or other usb devices to be charged even if the laptop is off.

If you battery is mounted this problem will not occur.

Solution: In the mobility center screen you will find a "Toshiba assist" button.  In the main screen of the Toshiba assist, click on the "Optimizer" button. Next select the **USB charging & sleep** button. There you will need to uncheck the cases (there are two, one for the battery mode and one for the main power mode. Don't forget to make apply at the right end corner.

The computer will now shut down normally, no fan will start running after it's shutdown.

You can reactivate USB charging by inverting the above procedure if you need to charge a phone during night.

Finally,as an alternate compromise, you can also stop the fan by holding the power button a few second while the fan has started to go crazy.

Denis.